# usb flash drive contents replaced with a single shortcut

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, virus, desktop, autorun

I was confused when I opened my flash drive all I saw was a shortcut with its target as

> C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe ~$WO.FAT32,_ldr@16 desktop.ini RET TLS " "

You may refer to the images I uploaded below. It shows the contents of the flash drive. The command prompt shows the hidden contents. You can see there that there is a  with a blank name. It contains the contents of the flash drive. That directory also has a desktop.ini inside it with these as contents.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=%systemroot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,7
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
IconIndex=7
```

Unlike the first desktop.ini (found at the root of the flash drive). It has some kind of binary contents which frankly I don't know how to paste here. So I just uploaded the contents of the flash drive [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7863zu6tcjfs3t/contents.zip). So you can view it yourself.

Another weird thing is the autorun.inf (which has only 0 bytes) is being used by the wuauclt.exe. You may refer to the second image below.

Has anyone experienced this too? I already did tried reformatting and reinserting the flash drive but still no luck.

[image: contents of flash drive]

[image: autorun is locked]

I hashed the desktop.ini (the binary-like one) and searched for it. It pointed me these links which was just posted a few days ago.

http://www.mycity.rs/Ambulanta/problem-sa-memorijskom-karticom-3.html

http://www.mycity.rs/Android/memoriska-kartica_2.html

desktop.ini (binary) d80c46bac5f9df7eb83f46d3f30bf426

I scanned the desktop.ini in VirusTotal. You may see the result [here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/c7bd252296272693d8ad658295de6ca89c6c0dd42c054ebb58f571aad1d8cc1f/analysis/1361503177/). McAfee-GW-Edition detected it as a **Heuristic.BehavesLike.Exploit.CodeExec.C**

I viewed the handles of wuauclt.exe in the Process Explorer and saw the autorun.inf is being used by the exe. You may also notice that a file from the temp folder is opened.

> AppData\Local\Temp\mstuaespm.pif

[Here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/fee15bde30df1a61b727c5bfdee96d348387b0e94a5a3d7b5cacad5c885da330/analysis/1361514924/) is the scan of that pif file from VirusTotal. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0prkqjevymsv9iy/mstuaespm.pif.zip) is an online copy of the PIF file and lastly, a [random file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlonjk7hgjlhvcd/Babojemi.baw.zip) that was generated after I ran the PIF file (I used sandbox).

[image: wuauclt]

Comment: It is turned on and I am using windows. So as far as I know, hidden files in Linux (.foldername) will still be shown in windows. (like the .Trash-0001 folder)

Comment: Maybe read up on this - http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds

Comment: If that is the case, won't it be showing in the Explorer like desktop.ini:virus.exe instead of just desktop.ini? (assuming that desktop.ini contains the virus)

Comment: If you have read the post, I already uploaded it and provided the link.

Comment: start .\test.txt:note.exe did not work in win 7 it says that there is no program associated to perform the requested action. and indicates an access is denied in the command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully removed it a few days back already. Though I just posted this one right now. Here is how I removed the backdoor from my computer.

http://blog.piratelufi.com/2013/02/usb-flash-drive-contents-replaced-with-a-single-shortcut/

Just realized that the question itself is not a very good question. It is something more of a topic for discussion. Thanks for the 'protection' though.

Comment: Damn, so it is a virus? I got this after plugging my flash drivce to a campus computer

Comment: Please, avoid providing an answer that is just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command prompt to copy your files to your internal HDD (Make sure you have a virus software installed and fully updated before doing this) and then scan the files before formatting the drive, and then put the files back on the drive.